# Unable to skip the Jquery-step

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am using Jquery-steps in a modal.In series of steps in that modal, I want to skip a step on certain conditions.Jquery-steps has h1 tag and fieldset tag.

I am hiding the h1 tag as follows

```js
$("#form-t-4").hide();
```

And I am hiding the fieldset as follows

```js
$("#form-p-4").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

But i am unable to click next step when this step has arrived.I dont want this step on certain conditions.

```js
mySteps.steps("remove", 5);
```

The above statement is also not working

Comment: Please, give some context to your questions, it is VERY difficult to know exactly what you are asking here. If possible try to include a small example that shows your problem.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on this. A working plunkr or JSfiddle would be highly appreciable.

Comment: I am using Jquery-steps in a modal.In series of steps in that modal, I want to skip a step on certain conditions.Jquery-steps has h1 tag and fieldset tag.

Comment: @AKA,@ProgrammerV5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, take the form element of jquery-steps.call remove on that.

$("#formid").steps("remove", 5);

where the form  tag contains h1 and fieldset's and for ex formid is the id of form.